# Where to decide whether component should show

Tags: angular

It's more of a conceptual question. I have a parent and a child component. I don't have a clear answer to where should I decide whether child component is visible.

- Is it in parent template, e.g. `<child *ngIf="showChild()">`?
- Or child should decide because it should have all knowledge about it?

Comment: When I was a child, my parents always had control. I think this is a universal concept ;-)

Comment: :), nice one. However you could think of encapsulating all login a child needs inside it.